# Environment.SpecialFolder in mono

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono, compatibility

I'm a starting learning mono, so it's new for me. I have a two questions. First:
Is Environment.SpecialFolder supported in mac and linux?
And second question:
What blogs or site you can recoment to read for research mono?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Here](http://ibboard.co.uk/Programming/mono-special-folders.html)'s a list of what works and what doesn't in Linux from the Environment.SpecialFolder list. This should be a good place to start. As for a Mono tutorial, [Monkeyguide](http://www.mono-project.com/Monkeyguide) could help you out.